# How to display only negative values of a matrix in red?

Tags: matlab, matrix, colormap

I work on matlab and I have a question:

I have a matrix:

```
M1 = [5000  5000  3000  4000
      11000 15000 13000 10000
      6000  8000  14000 9000]
```

And I subtract to this matrix 12000:

```
M2 = [7000  7000  9000  8000
      1000 -3000  -1000 2000
      6000  4000  -2000 3000]
```

I want to change the negative values to red while keeping the other values.

So the result would be: 
[image]

This is what i tried:

```
M1 = [5000 5000 3000 4000;
          11000 15000 13000 10000;
          6000 8000 14000 9000];


LmB = 12000;

M2 = LmB - M1;
M2(M2 < 0) = -1;
M2(M2 > 0) = 0;


figure;
imshow(M1, [], 'InitialMagnification','fit');

figure;
imshow(M2, [], 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');

cmap = [1 0 0; 0 0 0; 0 0 0];

% Apply colormap
colormap(cmap);
```

I have the negative values in red, but i don't know how to keep the other values and not change them in black.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Myself, I would make a logical mask `matrix<0`, set that to `nan`, plot it normally (i.e. with greyscale) then plot the reverse as logical mask and select a red colour for each element.

Comment: I tried to display one matrix with NaN for negative values then another matrix with negative values and the rest is NaN but I still get black for the NaN values, does imshow display what color is under NaN value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution: distort the colormap to fit your data.

If you define `M2` as:

```
M2 = LmB - M1;
M2(M2 < 0) = -max(M2(:));
```

Now the range of negative values and positive values is the same (they go from 0 to the same `abs()` value).

Using this, we can distort our colormap. All positives will be `gray`, all negatives, simply red.

```
red=[1 0 0];
cmap= gray;
cmap=[repmat(red,size(cmap,1),1); gray]; %half red, half gray
```

And plot:

```
imshow(M2, [], 'InitialMagnification', 'fit');
% Apply colormap
colormap(cmap);
```

[image]